# is my reasoning for enantiomers/meso compounds correct?

Tags: stereochemistry

[image]

I think a and b are enantiomers because a has R configuration but b has S configuration.

I think c and d are identical compounds which makes them a meso compound. If you just turn it 180 degrees they look the same to me. Am I right or is there something wrong with what I'm saying?

Comment: Related: [Confusion on enantiomers and meso compounds](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39472/7951)

Comment: Seems about right to me.