# Steroisomerism in cyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

What about stereochemistry of 1,2,3,4-tetrahdroxy cyclobutane 
How will we decide the stereocentre it's eating me can anybody help.

Answer is 4 stereoisomers

Comment: Related: [IUPAC name for 1,2,3-trichlorocyclopropane?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35486/7951) and [1,2,3-Trimethylcyclopropane stereoisomers](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/53507/7951)

Answer (score 2):

In the [RULES FOR THE NOMENCLATURE OF ORGANIC CHEMISTRY
SECTION E: STEREOCHEMISTRY](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1976/pdf/4501x0011.pdf), published in *Pure Appl. Chem.*, **1976**, *45*, 11-30, you find:

> **E—2.3.3.** When one substituent and one hydrogen atom
>   are attached at each of more than two positions of a
>   monocycle, the steric relations of the substituents are
>   expressed by adding *r* (for reference substituent), followed
>   by a hyphen, before the locant of the lowestnumbered
>   of these substituents and *c* or *t* (as appropriate),
>   followed by a hyphen, before the locants of the
>   other substituents to express their relation to the reference
>   substituent.

This means: pick one centre as a reference (*r*-1) and express the relative stereochemistry of the other centres, that is the relative orientation of the $\ce{OH}$ groups with respect to the reference, using *c* (if the substituent is on the same face of the ring) or *t* (if the substituent is on the opposite face of the ring).

Answer (score 0):

From what i see...at a basic point of view...there is no carbon with 4 different functional groups...hence i guess its optically inactive...as in each carbon is bonded to 2 identical carbons which are further bonded to the same carbon ...so the functional group dosent matter...Hopefully thats it

Comment: But it has 4 stereoisomers

Answer (score 0):

To solve this first we number the carbons as
[image]

Now when we consider cis form of 1 and 2 carbon there will be two stereoisomers cis and trans for 3 and 4 carbon

Now when we consider trans form of 1 and 2 carbon there will be two stereoisomers cis and trans for 3 and 4 carbon

Hence total 4 stereoisomers

[image]