# IUPAC nomenclature of 1,2,3,4-tetramethylcyclobutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

I'm having a hard time naming these molecule myself.

For the first molecule I start with one of the stereocenters, give priority "4" hydrogen and "3" to the attached CH3. How are the other two attached nodes given priority "1" and "2" in an anticlockwise fashion, like in the graph below?
For the second one I have the analogous problem, who is "1" and "2" in each stereocenter?

[image]

[image: an]

Comment: Related: [IUPAC name for 1,2,3-trichlorocyclopropane?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/) (may be dupe)

Comment: The first example contains pseudoasymmetric centers which have their own notation rules (page 21 http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/Chapter9.pdf). R has priority over S in assigning locants.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70293

Answer (score 4):

The Cahn-Ingold-Prelog (CIP) assignments of the configurations of the two tetramethylcyclobutanes above are accomplished as follows:
1)  Tetramethylcyclobutane **1**: This isomer has all of the methyl groups on the same face of the ring. There are two mirror planes passing through C<sub>1</sub>-C<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>-C<sub>4</sub>. Numbering the cis-isomer is arbitrary in that there is a 4-fold axis of symmetry present. The common methods for R/S-configurations do not apply. Because the ring carbons lie in symmetry planes, they are stereogenic and achirotopic requiring r/s-assignments. When an assignment is made to one carbon, the same assignment may be applied to the remaining three.
  Temporary assignments for **1a** are made to C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>4</sub> (r<sub>0</sub>/s<sub>0</sub>). Priorities are assigned at each of these carbons such that C<sub>1</sub> is the highest priority group.  Returning to C<sub>1</sub> the priorities are r<sub>0</sub>>s<sub>0</sub>>CH<sub>3</sub>>H. C<sub>1</sub> is of the s-configuration. Digraph **1b** illustrates the assignment to C<sub>1</sub> in a different way. The horizontal line represents the plane of the ring with C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>4</sub> above the plane of the ring and the dotted line (C<sub>1</sub>) signifies the carbon under assignment. Since r<sub>0</sub> precedes s<sub>0</sub>, C<sub>4</sub> precedes C<sub>2</sub>. C<sub>1</sub> is of the s-configuration.

2) Tetramethylcyclobutane **2**: This stereoisomer has ring carbons that are both stereogenic and chirotopic. Here R/S assignments apply. There is a plane of symmetry passing through the C<sub>1-4</sub> and C<sub>2-3</sub> bonds while a two-fold axis of rotation exists between the C<sub>1-2</sub> and C<sub>3-4</sub> bonds. Applying the methodology of **1a** to **2a**, C<sub>1</sub> is assigned the R-configuration. Referring to digraph **2b**, R<sub>0</sub>R<sub>0</sub> precedes R<sub>0</sub>S<sub>0</sub> [like(lk)>unlike(ul)]. Thus, C<sub>2</sub> precedes C<sub>4</sub>. C<sub>1</sub> is of the R-configuration.
One may apply this method to the remaining three ring carbons but there is a shortcut. Because C<sub>1</sub> mirrors C<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>4</sub> is of the S-configuration. The rotational axis shows that both C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> are of the R-configuration while C<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>4</sub> are both of the S-configuration. The numbering system requires that the lowest numbered atoms, if possible, be labeled R.

[image]